# Can Excel only display the results from a FILTER, ISNUMBER, SEARCH formula and not the entire array of searched data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, named-ranges

I am creating a spreadsheet that can search an entire "Control" data table using two search boxes.

- Search TextBox1 searches by UPI
- Search TextBox2 searches by Zip

The two search boxes are text boxes from the Developer--> Controls --> Insert --> ActiveX controls drop down.

Each text box is has a linked cell with C4 linked to UPI and C5 linked to Zip.

I am using the formula below to populate the columns of data from the Control table.

| UPI |
| --- |
| Formula below begins here beneath UPI Column and spills out the queried results to the remaining columns - in the order found on the Control table. |

```
=FILTER(Control, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C4, Control[UPI])) * ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C5, Control[Zip])), "No Match Found"
```

**Problem:** The formula works, however, when the search boxes are empty the entire Control table is viewable by the user.

I need a way to hide the Control table data so that only queried data is shown.

So, if both search boxes are empty then only the Column headers appear.

As the user begins entering a zip code into the zip search box - the search results begin to appear.

Is this possible?

The current formula begins with the entire Control table viewable and it narrows the Control table down to match what is being queried with each new number typed into the zip search box.

Is there a formula that can only display the search results? While keeping the Control table hidden? An =IF() or etc?

Comment: You will not be able to achieve the "search results begin to appear" in Excel in the way that you want. You would have to fire the worksheet calculate event on each key press. It would be cumbersome and end with the users being frustrated because I suspect that when the calculation fires, they won't be able to type.

Comment: What about `=IF(AND(TRIM(C4)="", TRIM(C5)=""),"Please choose search criteria", FILTER(Control,...))`?

Comment: @FlexYourData thanks for that. Is there a way to get the search results to begin to appear  following a users input in Excel? I know a data validation list can be searched and display the selected results? Is this the right approach as opposed to my formula?

Comment: Cell values only recalculate after you press enter, not upon each key press. I suspect the same goes for textboxes and it will only update the linked cell value once you hit enter or change focus. You could possibly use data validation or a dropdown box control to guide the user on what to search for, but the result will appear in the entry box, not the search results area.

Comment: On second though you might want to investigate using the keypress event. In theory you could update the cell value then as you type. You might have to carefully manage the focus, and a large file might induce some flickering or undesirable effects.